# How to use json for state in react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have data in JSON, and I use `SetState` in constructor

```
{
    index:index,
    key: key,
    all: {
         0: {name:'qwerty', id:'1', surname:'foo'}
         1: {name:'bar', id:'2', surname:'aaa'}
         2: {name:[
                0: {parent:'first'}
                1: {name:'second'}
              ]
            }
         }
    }
```

If I write `<span>{this.state.id}</span` in render everything works, but if I write something like `<span>{this.state.all.0.name}</span>` in Render or constructor, it doesn't work.

I try:

```
this.state.all.0.name
this.state.all[index].name  //this is let var index = 1
this.state.all[0].name
```

This is because I set state in constructor from promise, and for the 2 second my state I undefined, how I can render after promise load?

Comment: You should try `this.state.all['0']` As your key is a string, using a numeric value JS will try to access an object as an array which is incorrect.

Comment: That is JavaScript, not JSON!

Comment: @Adam — They said they tried `this.state.all[0].name` which is entirely equivelent to `this.state.all['0'].name`. With the exception of Symbols (which aren't used in this example), all property names are strings.

Comment: I'm find problem but I don't know how it do. I update question

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the index to access the values, use arrays instead of objects, like so:

```
this.state = {
  index:index,
  key: key,
  all: [
         {name:'qwerty', id:'1', surname:'foo'}, //0
         {name:'bar', id:'2', surname:'aaa'},    //1
         {name:[                                 //2
                 {parent:'first'},                   //0
                 {name:'second'},                    //1
               ],
         },
       ],

}
```

In this example, `this.state.all[2].name[0].parent === "first"`